# SQL Casting datetime and using it for groupby

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

Trying to find the hourly difference for each id within my org. here is my current query:

```
SELECT Label, SUM(Diff)
FROM (
        select distinct mr.deviceid, TO_CHAR(mr.readdate, 'MM/dd/yyyy HH:00 am') as Label, (MAX(ComputedReading) - MIN(ComputedReading)) AS Diff
        from analytic.twmeterreading as mr
         WHERE mr.ReadDate >= DATEADD(hour, -100, GetDate()) AND mr.ReadDate <= GetDate() and mr.orgunitid = 1
         group by mr.deviceid, Label
         order by label
     ) as ReadData
GROUP BY deviceid, Label
ORDER BY Label
```

The data types are:

readdate : datetime

deviceid : int

the readdate's are coming back in this format:

```
2018-08-17 07:01:16
2018-08-17 08:00:18
2018-08-17 14:59:41
2018-08-17 12:34:17
2018-08-17 06:02:06
2018-08-17 01:58:54
2018-08-17 12:02:14
2018-08-17 15:01:22
2018-08-17 11:03:16
2018-08-17 05:59:05
2018-08-17 14:02:29
2018-08-17 07:01:09
2018-08-17 09:58:17
2018-08-17 11:56:42
2018-08-17 02:01:13
2018-08-17 15:03:28
2018-08-17 06:03:45
2018-08-17 17:01:22
```

When I exclude the :00 am from the query, I get results back. I can not figure out why adding those as part of the query result in all 0's.

Example: 
for this type:  TO_CHAR(mr.readdate, 'MM/dd/yyyy') as Label

the result is this:

```
    label   sum
08/18/2018  108
08/18/2018  3
08/18/2018  254
08/18/2018  50
08/18/2018  229
08/18/2018  983
08/18/2018  434
08/18/2018  64
08/18/2018  2
08/18/2018  0
08/18/2018  370
```

when I do this: TO_CHAR(mr.readdate, 'MM/dd/yyyy hh:00 AM') as Label
I get back all 0's for the sum

Any idea? btw, this is on redshift if it matters

Comment: Why `'MM/dd/yyyy HH:00 am'`. why not `'MM/dd/yyyy HH:MI am'` ?

Comment: I am trying to not include the minutes. Just purely date and hours

Comment: Then, `'MM/dd/yyyy HH am'` ?

Comment: Sum is still zero. Not quite sure why when adding the am at the end the sum wont happen

Comment: Why include `deviceid` in sub-select and both `GROUP BY` if you don't use it at the end? And why `ORDER BY` in sub-select? Also, don't use `DISTINCT` and `GROUP BY`.

Comment: The deviceid in the sub-select is used to group the devices's usage per hour. If I remove this, it would just find the max and min for the whole group

Comment: Really the end goal is to sum all the devices's usage per day and print that

Comment: Well, if you're running it today with that data, the "last 100 hours" part will exclude all the data. Or did you exclude that/make fresh data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not clear on exactly what you want, but here is an example which seems to work:

```
SELECT deviceid, Label, SUM(Diff)
FROM (
        SELECT 
          mr.deviceid, 
          mr.readdate::date as Label, 
          (MAX(ComputedReading) - MIN(ComputedReading)) as Diff 
        FROM   twmeterreading as mr
        WHERE  mr.ReadDate::date >= current_date  
        AND    mr.ReadDate::date <= current_date 
        AND    mr.orgunitid = 1
        GROUP BY mr.deviceid, Label
     ) as ReadData
GROUP BY deviceid, Label
ORDER BY Label
```

Live code at: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/8f3c0/2

I used postgresql as that seems to be the closest to redshift. Note that the date conversion functions are a bit different.

Please comment on how close it is to your required answer, and I will adjust.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. It's fairly close. What i'm interested in is trying to get it over the past 24 hours in hour increments. When I modified your logic above to be to_char(date, 'hh am'), it comes back as all 12's. Not quite sure why. Would think it would be something like 1 AM, 5 pm, etc

Comment: Sorry, i should correct that. It does come back with the correct hour, it's the diff column, always comes as 0's

Comment: Done more more digging, so really each hour there is a recording, that's why it's coming back as 0's. is there an easy way to compare to the previous hours recording if it exists?